# Trying to write pyodbc executemany sql query

Tags: python, t-sql, pyodbc

Hello I am trying to write a query that checks if a key is in the table. If it is, I update the row. Otherwise, I insert the new key and its corresponding values into the table.

This is the query I am trying to run:

```
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE key= '?')  
        BEGIN  
            UPDATE table
            SET var1= '?',
                var2= ?,
                var3= ?,
                var4= ?
            WHERE key= '?'
        END  
        ELSE  
        BEGIN  
            INSERT INTO table (
                key, var1, var2, 
                var3, var4) 
            VALUES ('?', 
                '?',
                ?, 
                ?, 
                ?)
        END
```

However, when I try running this, pyodbc gives me this error:

```
cursorObject.executemany(sqlquery, recs)
('Expected 6 parameters, supplied 11', 'HY000')
```

For context, this is the format in recs:
`recs = [key, var1, var2, var3, var4, key, key, var1, var2, var3, var4]`

Comment: `'?'` isn't a parameter marker, it's just a literal string with the single character `?`; a parameter marker *does not* go inside single quotes (or any delimit identifier). As you have 5 instances of `'?'` and 6 with just `?`, you only have 6 parameter markers, and hence the error (as you've supplied 11). TL;DR: remove the single quotes around your parameter markers.

Comment: You are a good man. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

pyODBC expects question marks as placeholders in your query ([docs](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor)).

You seem to have mixed `'?'` and `?` as placeholders

But there is no need to surround the question mark for strings, it's actually causing your problem as they are evaluated as litteral strings containing only a question mark, no as placeholders.

This is the same as your query, but all `'?'` have been cleaned, making 11 placeholders.

```sql
    IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table WHERE key=?)  
        BEGIN  
            UPDATE table
            SET var1 = ?, var2 = ?, var3 = ?, var4 = ?
            WHERE key = ?
        END  
        ELSE  
        BEGIN  
            INSERT INTO table (key, var1, var2, var3, var4) 
            VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
        END
```